# How can I add right justified text to a TreeView Item in my VS Code extension

Tags: vscode-extensions

In my VS Code extension, I am using a TreeView to display some metrics, where each TreeItem has a 'name' and 'value'.  I can easily display the data like this (ignore the miss-alignment):

[image]

But I'd really like to force the 'value' to be right justified in the pane like this example from the debugger

[image]

Does anyone know how to achieve this result?

Comment: I take it the example you are showing is just part of the string assigned to the TreeItem label?  I doubt there is a way to do what you want via manipulating that string directly - I tried using a `.padEnd()` but the font isn't monospaced so it doesn't line up.

Comment: I assume a `WebView` could do what you want.

Comment: Ya I came to that conclusion - see below :)

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the code for the Call Stack view, it seems that it is not a treeView at all but built with custom HTML.

So I guess the answer to this question is: "you can't"